# Python: xpath.find() won't find new elements if they were added without namespace

Tags: python, xml, xpath, python-2.7, xml-namespaces

Today I stumbled upon a peculiar behaviour of the `xml.dom` and `xpath` modules and it took me a while to figure out it had to do with XML namespaces:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import xpath

zooXml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Zoo xmlns='http://foo.bar/zoo'>
  <Compound><Chimp/></Compound>
</Zoo>"""

mydom = minidom.parseString(zooXml)
compound = xpath.findnode('/Zoo/Compound', mydom)
print compound.toxml() # as expected: <Compound><Chimp/></Compound>
print xpath.find("Chimp", compound) # as expected: [<DOM Element: Chimp at 0x24c0cc8>]
```

So far so good, but if I now add another `Chimp` element without explicitly specifying its namespace, `xpath` won't find the new element:

```
newChimp = mydom.createElement("Chimp")
compound.appendChild(newChimp)
print compound.toxml() # ok, two chimps now: <Compound><Chimp/><Chimp/></Compound>
print xpath.find("Chimp", compound) # wait a second, that's still only one chimp: [<DOM Element: Chimp at 0x24a0d88>]
```

After re-parsing the modified XML, xpath will find both elements:

```
mydom = minidom.parseString(mydom.toxml())
compound = xpath.findnode('/Zoo/Compound', mydom)
print xpath.find("Chimp", compound) # now it finds both chimps: [<DOM Element: Chimp at 0x24c9808>, <DOM Element: Chimp at 0x24c9888>]
```

Also, if I create new elements with namespace, `xpath` will find them without re-parsing:

```
babyChimp = mydom.createElementNS(mydom.firstChild.namespaceURI, "Chimp")
compound.appendChild(babyChimp)
print xpath.find("Chimp", compound) # that worked: [<DOM Element: Chimp at 0x24c9808>, <DOM Element: Chimp at 0x24c9888>, <DOM Element: Chimp at 0x24c9548>]
```

The question is: is this behaviour correct or is it a bug? Shouldn't the namespace of `Chimp` be implicit? After all, the XML generated will be the same, regardless of whether I use `xml.dom.createElement()` or `xml.dom.createElementNS()`. And if this is a bug, then where is it? In `xml.dom` or in `xpath`?

FWIW: I observed this behaviour with the Windows distributions of Python 2.7.5 as well as 2.7.4 and in both cases I used [xpath](http://code.google.com/p/py-dom-xpath/) module 0.1.

Comment: It could be a bug, but not where you think. I'd also suggest explicitly adding the namespace of the element would be appropriate course of action here.

As I see it there are two possible bugs. Either its not parsing the XML properly when you add an element without a namespace or its not serialising the XML correctly and isn't adding a null namespace when it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Briefly:

> The question is: is this behaviour correct or is it a bug?

The behaviour seems incorrect or at least unwanted so I would say it's either bug or unfinished feature.

> Shouldn't the namespace of `Chimp` be implicit?

It is implicit when parsing a string, but it is not implicit when creating and adding that element to tree.

> After all, the XML generated will be the same, regardless of whether I use `xml.dom.createElement()` or `xml.dom.createElementNS()`.

The generated XML is not the same or at least it should not be the same.

> And if this is a bug, then where is it?

I'm guessing there is a bug in the `toxml()` method and it doesn't output the empty default namespace of the second `Chimp` element and thus it inherits the default namespace from the `Zoo` element when the modified document is re-parsed.

### To be more precise:

First your document is

```
<Zoo xmlns='http://foo.bar/zoo'>
  <Compound><Chimp/></Compound>
</Zoo>
```

Then you try to find the `Chimp` element but you do not define for it any namespace context. However it seems that in such case the `xpath` module initializes the context from the document element of the node, so the find succeeds.

Then you add another `Chimp` element, but without the namespace, and your document becomes

```
<Zoo xmlns='http://foo.bar/zoo'>
  <Compound><Chimp/><Chimp xmlns=""/></Compound>
</Zoo>
```

The second find attempt returns only one element, because the other one has different namespace.

I'm guessing the bug happens here so that, instead of the correct version above, the output of the `toxml()` method actually is

```
<Zoo xmlns='http://foo.bar/zoo'>
  <Compound><Chimp/><Chimp/></Compound>
</Zoo>
```

Re-parsing that text causes the second `Chimp` element to inherit the same (default) namespace than the first one and therefore your third find returns 2 elements.

Adding the last `Chimp` element will cause the document to become

```
<Zoo xmlns='http://foo.bar/zoo'>
  <Compound><Chimp/><Chimp/><Chimp xmlns='http://foo.bar/zoo'/></Compound>
</Zoo>
```

which is completely same as

```
<Zoo xmlns='http://foo.bar/zoo'>
  <Compound><Chimp/><Chimp/><Chimp/></Compound>
</Zoo>
```

Again, all the `Chimp` elements are in the same namespace so find returns them all.

This bug seems relevant: http://bugs.python.org/issue1371937  Despite its status, it actually is still open since it is closed as duplicate of another open bug.

Comment: Back then, when I asked this question here on stackoverflow, I also created a bug item which appears to be still open: http://bugs.python.org/issue18182